# Convert string value to Geography data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a Location column. This column is a varchar(255) at present stored from a spreadsheet. It contains a long SRID string value, like this example: `0xE6100000010C61C3D32B65A14440C4B12E6EA3BD5BC0`

Question, I have a need to take that value as is, and store it in my addresses table as a Geography data type. When I look in the addresses table, I see other Location data that exists and it looks exactly as my example value above.

However, when I try and use the `Convert(Geography, Location)` from my Select statement, I get this error:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":
>
> System.FormatException: 24114: The label 0xE6100000010C1F6FA8 in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type only).
>       System.FormatException:...

How do I convert or cast this existing `varchar` data to the already existing Geography data in my addresses table?

Comment: The SRID should be an integer value right?

Comment: How exactly is your example SRID a valid value?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stgeomfromwkb-geography-data-type This function requires a binary argument and an SRID. Something does not add up with your source data.

Comment: It goes as a .csv file through a mapping service to insert the value along with longitude and latitude. From there, it ends up in a imports table as a string value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the geography::STGeomFromWKB, which needs a binary value and a SRID as input.
The problem you have a binary value stored in a varchar, and converting/casting it to binary will actually make it something different.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql about Binary Data Types.

Try elaborating on the following example (works on my SQL 2014):

```
DECLARE @location varchar(255)='0xE6100000010C61C3D32B65A14440C4B12E6EA3BD5BC0'

DECLARE @binlocation varbinary (max)=CONVERT(varbinary(max), @location, 1)

DECLARE @b geography

SET @b=@binlocation

SELECT @b.ToString()
```

Comment: What am I missing? I am trying to use your code above as`BEGIN TRANSACTION
   WHILE ( @ROWCOUNTER <= @ROWCOUNT )
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @location varchar(max)
    DECLARE @binlocation varbinary (max)=CONVERT(varbinary(max), @location)
    DECLARE @b geography
    SET @b=@binlocation
    
/* Insert Ship To Addresses */
    INSERT INTO dbo.Addresses
    (
     ,Location
     ,Longitude
     ,Latitude
    )
    SELECT 
     ,@b.ToString()
     ,Convert(Float, I.Longitude)
     ,Convert(Float, I.Latitude)
    FROM dbo.ImportsCustomers I
    WHERE I.Id = @ID;`

Comment: it imports without error, however the location field in the Addresses table is NULL, so it's not populating with data. It's hard to read above, but here is what I have: `DECLARE @location varchar(max)
    DECLARE @binlocation varbinary (max)=CONVERT(varbinary(max), @location)
    DECLARE @b geography
    SET @b=@binlocation`

Comment: any news on this??

Comment: Yes, I actually ended up using the latitude and longitude values to re-create the location (SRID) value of each row on import to the Addresses table. The code I used was this: `geography::STGeomFromText('POINT('+I.Longitude+' '+I.Latitude+')', 4326)` and it works like a charm. I could not get the existing Location value to happily convert to the geograpghy data type that was needed. Most likely something I was doing wrong, just couldn't figure it out at the time. Thank you Antonio, your example led me down the path to discovering my solution.